# bad md5sum error when trying to customize ubuntu-keyring-udeb

Tags: installation, custom-distributions, custom-installer, debian-installer

I have been trying to customize Ubuntu 8.04 (hardy heron) alternate install cd. I have followed the community documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Generating_a_new_ubuntu-keyring_.deb_to_sign_your_CD to rebuild the ubuntu-keyring packages. But when the media boots I get a warning:

```
anna[7581]: WARNING **: bad md5sum.
```

Though I have not been able to confirm that the message is for the ubuntu-keyring-udeb package, the nearest debconf Adding [package] message is for ubuntu-keyring-udeb.

This is followed by:

```
INPUT critical retriever/cdrom/error.
```

This message is already from syslog. I don't think dpkg.log will help in this case. I have tried modifying the md5sum file within the source package manually and signing it with my own public key, before building it. But that has not helped either.

How do get the installer to work in this scenario? Alternatively, can I customize the contents of Ubuntu 8.04 without signing anything?

Comment: I used the scripts from uck-remaster*  http://fabrizioballiano.net/2007/11/27/remastering-an-ubuntu-alternate-iso-with-ubuntu-customization-kit-the-complete-guide/.

I tried going through the code and everything seems almost similar to what I have done. I am yet to figure out what I did wrong though. However, The scripts worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same issue when using the same instructions.  In my case I was directly following the community documentation using an LTS version of Precise Pangolin and ended up downloading the most up-to-date version of the ubuntu-keyring source.  I noticed when copying keys the ones I created were 2011.11.21.1.

I moved back a version by using

```
apt-get source ubuntu-keyring=2011.11.21
```

After this everything seemed to work closer to as described.  [This post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/uck/+bug/1042703) pointed me in the right direction.